# NSManagedObject - NSSet gets removed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an nsmanagedObject this NSManagedObject contains an NSSet.

the data for NSSet get's lost when i call release on an NSManagedObject with retain count of 2.

Wouldn't retaining an NSManagedObject also retain all it's properties??

```
- (id)initViewWithManagedObject :(NSManagedObject)obj
{
     if (self = [super init])
     {
          self.managedObject = obj;
     }
     return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
     self.managedObject = nil;
     //Here is when the nsset data gets removed

     [super dealloc];
}
```

Below describes how the property was created

```
@interface MyManagedObject :NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *mySet;
@end

@implementation MyManagedObject
@dynamic mySet;
@end
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the solution to the problem:
I had to create both way relationship from object a to b and from object b to a.
For example:

```
CountryManagedObject *country = [Factory getCountryByName:@"USA"];
StateManagedObject *state = [Factory createStateByName:@"California"];
[country.statesSet addObject:state]; //assuming NSSet responds to addObject
//the line below fixed the problem
//State has a reversed relationship to country named "country"
state.country = country;
```

Comment: Assuming Core Data and your setters are set up correctly, you should never have to manually define the reciprocal relationship—core data does that for you automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you calling `[self.managedObject release]`? You should *never* call `-release` on the results of calling a getter. The appropriate code here is simply `[managedObject release]` (assuming `managedObject` is the name of the backing ivar).

Furthermore, once you release the object, why are you inspecting its properties?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Your original problem is predicated upon inspecting the contents of a property of an object after you've released the object. Can you restate your problem such that this doesn't happen?

Comment: This is a core data object (NSManagedObject), When i say NSSet data get's lost I mean permanently, so next time that i make a fetch and retrieve the same object the NSSet is Empty. The way to get rid of the loss is by not releasing the NSMAnagedObject in dealloc method which causes a leak.

Comment: Are you saving your context before any release operation happens?

Comment: No I save the context every time the app suspends

Comment: So post your code, specially where you instantiate your object and add the related objects via its relationships, and then save the context.

Comment: +1 Retaining and releasing managed objects is only slightly less dangerous than playing Russian roulette with five chambers loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe to assume your application is getting an NSSet which you want to be a Core Data relationship?

In the case, the problem isn't around releasing and retaining. The problem is you aren't saving the managed object context before you're done with the object, so when you fetch again, the data is lost.